# sql smallest value with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, Article and Image with one-to-many where Article is the parent and the Image has foreign key column `article_id`. Each Image also has the column `position` that is `integer`.

Now what I need is to I get all of the articles, regardless if there are any images for all of them, but for those that have one ore more images it needs to return a single image which has the lowest position stored in `position` column.

In other words along the pseudo lines:

```
SELECT FROM ALL ARTICLES LEFT JOIN IMAGES (WHERE IMAGE FOR THIS ARTICLE HAS SMALLEST POSITION)
```

What SQL query to get the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot give a precise answer without knowing your schema, but in essence you want to get the [groupwise minimum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Article LEFT JOIN (
         Images NATURAL JOIN (
           SELECT   article_id, MIN(position) AS position
           FROM     Images
           GROUP BY article_id
         ) AS t
       ) USING (article_id)
```

Comment: @Tarik here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbe2d/8  all set up with both of your queries slighly altered just to reflect the actual schema naming/structure, otherwise as original, both seem to be broken (just uncomment to run)

Comment: Sweet, works like a charm I see you basically changed USING to ON in the last line, this was causing the issue. Thanks, took me some hair pulling.

Comment: @grants: Yes, the structure of the `Article` table was absent from your question and I originally assumed that it had a column titled `article_id` rather than `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ARTICLES AS art
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT article_id, image_id,
                 MIN(Position) AS Position
   FROM Images
   GROUP BY article_id, image_id) AS MinPos
 LEFT JOIN Images AS img ON
MinPos.article_id = img.article_id AND
MinPos.image_id = img.image_id
```

Comment: Could not test my query. Please post table schema and data in sqlfiddle.com.